# How do I debug software that outputs a .mix?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I stumbled upon a github repository that has some source code for a maphack on an old but popular RTS game. Anyway, I downloaded the source from the github repository and starting looking through it using visual studio.

When I try and debug this software, Visual studio notifies me that the application.mix is not a valid win32 application. So my question is, how do I debug this code?

The source code's readme says that I need to put the ".mix" file into the video game's source directory, which I have done. I then tried attaching the visual studio debugger to the video game's explorer process while I had the source code loaded in visual studio, but no breakpoints were hit (I put a break point on almost every method, it's really not that much code).

Thanks

Comment: Did you use Visual Studio to compile the code to this "mix" file?

Comment: I'm not sure, let me cut the file out and put it somewhere else to see if it's recreated.

Comment: @user4581301 I removed the file, rebuild solution, and the application.mix file is recreated

Comment: You should be able to switch the build options to generate a debug version that respects breakpoints. Move the debug version to the game, make sure the game is loading your mix file ([Sysinternals process explorer or process monitor should help there](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx)) and then either run the game and attach to the debugger like you did, or use the debugger to run the program directly.

Comment: Does the 'mix' file contain executable code or resources?  A quick google search suggests that a '.mix' file contains microsoft image exchange data (coming from PhotoDraw 2000) that consists of vector and rastor drawings.

Comment: Also, can you add a link to the github repository so we can look a the same code as you are?